# anybody working or heard of qcubed/qcodo mvc frameworks?

Tags: php

I have been using qcodo/qcubed for developing CMS based sites. I had been successful in developing and maintaining fairly complex sites using these frameworks.

Things get done so quick and easy using qcubed that i never felt the need to look for another framework like zend, symfony ....

I am wondering if you guys have tried or have been using them.

I have not tried zend, symfony, kohana or other frameworks of discusson on reddit.

What is your opinion, is qcubed as good as these frameworks? If not can you please suggest some of the features that you find useful in other frameworks and are missing from qcubed.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about **qcodo**. I took a quick look at the code and I find it somewhat bloated, however that doesn't mean it's a bad framework.

**CakePHP** is also bloated, I don't have any experience with it but I don't find it *sexy* enough. **Lithium** on the other hand seems like another story.

**Zend Framework**, while huge, has an impressible amount of libraries that can be used in standalone.

Regarding **CodeIgniter** and it's fork **Kohana**, both are extremely fast and lightweight - they provide a small learning curve that allows developers to get things done quickly.

One other framework that is probably less known is [**Akelos**](http://www.akelos.org/), I've never used it but it seems a pleasure to work with after watching the screencasts. It's also extremely powerful.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try for `Cake PHP`? because most of the features of MVC has been perfectly covered in Cake.

```
this is just my suggestion...
```